# Is there a service to keep my contacts synchronised?

Tags: webapp-rec

I need to keep my contacts in sync across several devices: smartphone, dumb phone, PC, and also have access to them on the web from any connected device.

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google](http://google.com/contacts/) ecosystem [syncs](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/) contacts pretty good.

Comment: We sync calendar entries and mails too, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two services you may like:

- [Soocial](http://www.soocial.com/)
- [Plaxo](http://www.plaxo.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I use a service called MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also ver cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [OVI service](http://www.ovi.com/services/) of Nokia syncs between several devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [google](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/) and ovi service - here are a few more...

[Mobile me](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/) works with IPhone, IPad, Mac and PC - so useful for Apple related hardware.

You could use [Microsoft Phone Data Manager](http://specials.msn.co.in/sp09/pdm/index.asp) which syncrhonises data from a variety of mobile phones and a PC.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this one....kylook.com is a new option

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why this is an option.