# How to auto sync Yahoo! contacts with Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts, email, synchronization, contacts, yahoo

I'm using Yahoo! as my primary mail agent, so my contacts are there. Now I decided to put all my contacts from different social networks (LinkedIn, Facebook, Thunderbird..) onto one Google Contact; this will help in organizing things by having a master [Unified Address Book](http://lifehacker.com/5676676/use-google-contacts-as-a-unified-address-book).. So when I update my Google contacts (delete, add or modify a contact) i want the changes the changes apply automatically to Yahoo! contacts.

The only available solution now inside Yahoo! is to import the contacts manually but I need an automatic solution.. any ideas?

Comment: If you have access to Outlook this might be easier.  Just sync Outlook and Yahoo together then sync Outlook with Google.

Comment: That was kinda the point of [Soocial](http://www.soocial.com/), but they've [decided to discontinue the product](http://blog.soocial.com/2013/07/01/we-are-shutting-down-soocial-com/). Alternatives might be [Full Contact](http://www.fullcontact.com/) (beta), [Memotoo](http://www.memotoo.com), or [Plaxo](http://www.plaxo.com/).

Comment: See also: [Is there a service to keep my contacts in sync?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/674)

Comment: None of the solutions proposed really addresses the problem; For Outlook, It adds another layer of complexity besides, I'm not really a fun of Microsoft products; I prefer Thunderbird instead.. The bottom line is; there's no solution available yet as the war between yahoo/google/microsoft in terms of contacts backup is not settled yet; everyone of them NEEDS our contacts!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

kylook lets you sync yahoo with google. Site is not the most robust but works - http://kylook.com